# How to resolve 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, opera

I know there are several posts on this topic but I couldn't find one that answers my question so allow me to indulge you a little.

Mine is a simple HTML5 project, fetching data from ASP.NET WebForm (VB.NET 2010/2012) and having Javascript read the values off a variable like this:

```
var myBSValues = BSValues.value; //Code fails / breaks here with the error above
```

BSValues is a HiddenField control in ASP.NET WebForm that gets assigned a string value in the page as follows:

```
Me.BSValues.value = "Hello World, A new World, Going to Heaven"
```

In JavaScript, I split the text at the commas (,) to create an array which I use to create a dynamic table and populate its cells for display.

I believe that is a simple enough solution and a simple explanation of it. Good news is the procedure works in:

1. FireFox 14
2. Chrome 27
3. Safari 5

but fails in:

1. IE 9 & 10, with the error message above at the line assigning the values in JavaScript,
2. Opera 12 (I don't know how to get an error message, it just doesn't show anything)

I think there is a large user base on IE so I would really like to make it work for IE.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
var myBSValues = document.getElementById("BSValues").value;
```

Comment: Thanks. This has also enabled me to see how much more errors aspx will catch if browser is set to IE; as opposed to when I am using the others. I have really had to clean up my JavaScript code - no assumptions.